# Page response time is high when running load, but low when loading it manually

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner, stress-testing

I am using Loadrunner to test the webpage(which we built). The problem here i am facing is after execution of the test, the loadrunner reports were showing too high response time for login page(1st page after entering URL) and after login page like 20-30 seconds. But manually its not even taking 2 seconds. Can anyone explain me why like this?

Comment: How many vusers are your running in the test?

Comment: @Levi 16 virtual users

Comment: Define what and how you are measuring in each context.  Also, is this for one user in each case?  Are you measuring at the MDRV level, the VUGEN level or other?  How much logging do you have in place?  Are you running the run time browser (in VUGEN)?  Is your load generator overloaded?

Comment: Run one user, turn off all logging, turn off the runtime browser, turn off animated replay, set "sensitivity" to "0" (zero) on the additional attributes.  Then compare the times for one in VUGEN to the time for one run manually.

Answer (score -2):

1) Check whether application sending parallel request to the server.
   if yes, Use web_concurrent_start() and web_concurrent_end() function.Which supports only 'url' mode recording.

When user launches the multiple browser instance from same machine.It will give more response time. It depends on application, you have to check with Development team.